# What is the use of FXCollections.observableArrayList?

Tags: javafx-2

In Javafx 2.X used Choice Box

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
   "New Document", "Open ", 
    new Separator(), "Save", "Save as")
);
```

In Table view used for FXCollection.observableArraylist.

why used for observableArraylist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns an ArrayList which can be observed for changes (new items added/ removed).